# Google Workspace (GMail) Add on: Reading email address only

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

Using one of Google API's I need to extract just the email addresses of those included in an email. Is this possible without having to go through the Security assessment? I don't need the content of the email just the addresses.

Comment: It seems like this is the access I need: But not sure if accessing this will still require an expensive security review.

Read open message metadata https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.message.metadata
Grants temporary access to the open message's metadata

Comment: Email addresses are a form of personally identifiable information, so your application will have to undergo a security assessment to ensure you are not misusing that information in some way.

Comment: Does this apply also if I just want the app in Workspaces and not for standard gmail users? 

From Google: "To better ensure that user expectations align with developer uses, the following policies will apply to apps accessing user data from consumer Google accounts (Note: as always, G Suite admins have the ability to control access to their users’ applications. Read more.)."

Comment: Are you talking about emails that you receive?  What's the scope of your request?

Comment: What do you mean by those included in an email?

Comment: It is basically a google workspace add-on that uses the email address in a given email.

Comment: I don't see why you can't get the emails addresses in emails that you received without a security assessment.  You can get the message id and the from and the to and the body without any security issues by calling a google apps script on the server to return them to the addon.

Comment: I have an addon that deletes all of my trash and any emails in the inbox or the spam folder that are not in my contact list. And I can run it all from a Gmail Addon even the addon on my iphone.  It's my answer to a spam filter and it keeps my trash clean.

Comment: Do you want to publish the app publicly? If you want to publish it privately, with your own Workspace domain (and not for other domains), there's no need to go through any security assessment. Otherwise, this assessment would be needed, since access to the message headers requires a `Restricted` scope. [Gmail scopes](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/scopes#gmail_scopes).

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately no, as you will need access to a user's inbox (yours or somebody else's) in order to have access to their messages.  This will generate a permissions dialog.

> *If your app requests any of the following scopes, and doesn't meet any of the criteria for an exception (see below), you will need to satisfy both the API Services User Data Policy and the Additional Requirements for Specific Scopes, which requires a more extensive review process.*
>
> *https://mail.google.com/ (includes any usage of IMAP, SMTP, and POP3 protocols)*
> *https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly*
> *https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.metadata*
> *https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify*
> *https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.insert*
> *https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose*
> *https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.basic*
> *https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.sharing*
>
> Source: https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914#restricted-scopes&zippy=%2Cgmail-drive-and-google-fit-apis

EDIT:

As Iamblichus pointed out, if you are just wanting to use this for yourself then you can publish it privately.